# API Get request being blocked outside of network

Tags: api, rest, networking, axios, wireshark

I built a web app using `React` and uses `Axios` to make api calls.

The web application sits on our public server, while the API sits on one of our servers inside our network.

When I or any user use the application while VPN into our network the api request goes through. However, when we try outside of the network we get a timeout error.

I'm able to access the website perfectly fine outside the network with no errors. The timeout error happens when I submit the form and do the `axios.get`

I have wireshark running on the server where the web application is sitting and below is what errors I'm receiving with trying to make that api call.

[image]

What would be causing the TCP Retransmission to switch ports from 443 t0 53027 (which is a dynamic port that changes on every session). What's causing the timeout?